Javascript Intersection Observer API problem
I have a problem related to the Intersection observer API in Javascript.
I wrote a little code where a svg "draws itself" when it enters the viewport and "erases itself" whet it goes out.
The problem appears only whith the first appearance of the .svg, with a kind of glich. The svg appears entirely and disappears quicky before drawing itself.
That "glitch" happened only with the first appearance.
This is the html code (of course, Lorem5000 stands for 5000 words):
  <div>Lorem5000</div>


<svg id="svg1" width="210mm" height="297mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 210 297" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="m66.694 68.511a64.589 39.591 0 0159.486 18.831 64.589 39.591 0 01.29525 41.038 64.589 39.591 0 01-59.213 19.152" fill="none" stroke="#000048" stroke-miterlimit="4.1" stroke-width="22.861"/>
   </svg>

Here is the CSS:
svg {
    width: 60%;
    /* position: fixed; */
    top: 5%;
    left: 20%;
}
svg path {
    stroke-dasharray: 0;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke-width: 30;
    stroke:blue;
    fill: none;  
}

And at last, this is the JS code:

let paths = document.querySelectorAll('path');
const svg = document.querySelector('svg');

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {

  entries.forEach(function(entry) {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
     
      if (entry.intersectionRatio >= 0.3) {
        console.log("visible");
        for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
          let path = paths[i];
          let pathLength = path.getTotalLength();

          path.style.strokeDasharray = pathLength;
          path.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength;

          setTimeout(function() {

            
            path.style.transition = 'stroke-dashoffset 1s';
            path.style.strokeDashoffset = 0;
          }, i * 100);
        }
      }
    } else {
      console.log("pas visible");
      for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
        let path = paths[i];
        let pathLength = path.getTotalLength();
        
       
        path.style.transition = 'stroke-dashoffset 2s';
        path.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength;
      }
    }
  });
}, { threshold: 0.3 });

observer.observe(document.querySelector("#svg1"));

Can someone please help me fix that curious glitch?
Thanks in advance.
Didier

An IntersectionObserver does fire when it's been connected. So you'll get a first call where entry.isIntersecting will be false:


const observer = new IntersectionObserver(([{ isIntersecting }]) => {
  console.log({ isIntersecting });
});
observer.observe(document.querySelector("p"));
p { margin-top: 300vh; }
<p>target</p>



Doing so, you'll set your path's strokeDashoffset to pathLength, but its strokeDasharray will still be 0, from the CSS. Thus, it will be fully stroked anyway and you'll see it when it enters the screen:


const path = document.querySelector("path");
const pathLength = path.getTotalLength();
path.style.transition = "stroke-dashoffset 2s";
path.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength;

document.querySelector("button").onclick = (evt) => {
  path.style.strokeDasharray = pathLength;
  path.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength;
  setTimeout(() => {
    path.style.transition = 'stroke-dashoffset 1s';
    path.style.strokeDashoffset = 0;
  });
};
svg path {
    stroke-dasharray: 0;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke-width: 30;
    stroke:blue;
    fill: none;  
}
<button>simulate intersection</button>
<svg id="svg1"  viewBox="0 40 210 297" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="m66.694 68.511a64.589 39.591 0 0159.486 18.831 64.589 39.591 0 01.29525 41.038 64.589 39.591 0 01-59.213 19.152" fill="none" stroke="#000048" stroke-miterlimit="4.1" stroke-width="22.861"/>
</svg>



To avoid that, you could set the strokeDasharray outside of the observer's callback:


let paths = document.querySelectorAll('path');
const svg = document.querySelector('svg');

// Set the dash-array of every path
for (const path of paths) {
  const pathLength = path.getTotalLength();
  path.style.strokeDasharray = pathLength;
}

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
  entries.forEach(function(entry) {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {

      if (entry.intersectionRatio >= 0.3) {
        console.log("visible");
        for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
          let path = paths[i];
          let pathLength = path.getTotalLength();

          path.style.strokeDasharray = pathLength;
          path.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength;

          setTimeout(function() {
            path.style.transition = 'stroke-dashoffset 1s';
            path.style.strokeDashoffset = 0;
          }, i * 100);
        }
      }
    } else {
      console.log("pas visible");
      for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
        let path = paths[i];
        let pathLength = path.getTotalLength();

        path.style.transition = 'stroke-dashoffset 2s';
        path.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength;
      }
    }
  });
}, {
  threshold: 0.3
});

observer.observe(document.querySelector("#svg1"));
.lorem {
  height: 120vh;
}

svg {
  width: 60%;
  /* position: fixed; */
  top: 5%;
  left: 20%;
}

svg path {
  stroke-dasharray: 0;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke-width: 30;
  stroke: blue;
  fill: none;
}
<div class="lorem">Lorem5000</div>

<svg id="svg1" width="210mm" height="297mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 210 297" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="m66.694 68.511a64.589 39.591 0 0159.486 18.831 64.589 39.591 0 01.29525 41.038 64.589 39.591 0 01-59.213 19.152" fill="none" stroke="#000048" stroke-miterlimit="4.1" stroke-width="22.861"/>
</svg>



But I can't help to note that you're using a weird setTimeout in the visible call. I suppose this is to avoid the fact the transition wouldn't apply otherwise. If that's the case, I invite you to have a look at the Web Animations API instead. It's much more cleaner and performant:


let paths = document.querySelectorAll('path');
const svg = document.querySelector('svg');

// Set the dash-array of every path
for (const path of paths) {
  const pathLength = path.getTotalLength();
  path.style.strokeDasharray = pathLength;
}

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
  entries.forEach(function(entry) {
    for (let i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
      const path = paths[i];
      const pathLength = path.getTotalLength();
      if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
        console.log("pas visible");
        path.animate([
          { strokeDashoffset: pathLength },
        ], { duration: 2000, fill: "forwards" });
      }
      else if (entry.intersectionRatio >= 0.3) {
        console.log("visible");
        path.animate([
          { strokeDashoffset: pathLength },
          { strokeDashoffset: 0 },
        ], { duration: 1000, fill: "forwards", delay: i * 100 });
      }
     }
  });
}, { threshold: 0.3 });

observer.observe(document.querySelector("#svg1"));
.lorem {
  height: 120vh;
}
svg {
    width: 60%;
    /* position: fixed; */
    top: 5%;
    left: 20%;
}
svg path {
    stroke-dasharray: 0;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke-width: 30;
    stroke:blue;
    fill: none;  
}
<div class="lorem">Lorem5000</div>

<svg id="svg1" width="210mm" height="297mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 210 297" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="m66.694 68.511a64.589 39.591 0 0159.486 18.831 64.589 39.591 0 01.29525 41.038 64.589 39.591 0 01-59.213 19.152" fill="none" stroke="#000048" stroke-miterlimit="4.1" stroke-width="22.861"/>
</svg>




Thank you very much for your answers, Kaiido. It helps me a lot!
